# how can I restrict access to my aws dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I would like to restrict access to my dynamodb table. I would want to have the same kind of functionality as with for exmaple with AD groups, you could check if a user is a part of a specific AD group and give access based on that.

What is the idiomatic way in AWS to restrict access to an aws dynamodb where the users are authenticated with cognito?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [IAM policy **Condition**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html).

You can refer also to this [Using IAM policy conditions for fine-grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)

Answer (score 1):

For any [federated access](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) to AWS, the user authenticates via their IdP and gets in return a set of AWS credentials associated with an AWS IAM role. You can use federated user attributes for [access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp.html).